# Multiply counter value with corresponding counter key function in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

say I got following output containing several counter objects from several lists:

```
for b in data:  
    m = np.sum(b.values()) 
    individuals = [i for i in b.values() if i != 0]
    counter = collections.Counter(individuals)
```

**Output**:

```
Counter({1: 10, 2: 2})
Counter({1: 19, 4: 1, 5: 1})
Counter({1: 14, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 2})
Counter({1: 12, 3: 5, 2: 3, 4: 2, 6: 1, 9: 1})
Counter({1: 14, 3: 4, 4: 4, 2: 3, 5: 1, 8: 1, 10: 1})
```

Now what I am trying to do is to raise `float(i)/m` to the second power for each key in the counter object, 
but additionally, I need to select the corresponding counter.value() and multiply it with `float(i)/m`. How can I integrate a 
second for loop with `counter.values()`?

```
 f = np.sum( float(i)/m**2 for i in counter.keys() )
```

Comment: Never ever compare integers with `is`! I'll change the `if i is not 0` to `if i != 0` for you.

Comment: It seems that you want to operate on both keys and values at the same time. Are you looking for ``counter.items()`` perhaps? Otherwise, can you please clarify how your value operations relate to the key operations?